# How to persistent headers or properties in camel route in multicast()?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to find a way to persistent headers or properties (or anything) in my camel route. I have camel route like this:

```
from("direct:start").bean("injectHeader").multicast().to("direct:internal", "direct:external")
                    .end().bean("c");
                from("direct:internal").bean("a");
                from("direct:external").bean("b");
```

In `a`, I set some header to be something, but it is not persistent in `b` and `c`. Only headers set from `b` is persistent in `c`. (Same goes with properties)

I am not sure why this is happening with multicast(). If I remove multicast(), headers is persistent. However, I do need to use multicast().

How can I keep a value persistent throughout the route in multicast()?

Answer (score -1):

To persist property , you need a processor instead of bean. Bean is an endoint that consumes only the exchange body . Processor has the entire exchange

Change your code to

```
from("direct:start")
  .process( exchange -> {
    exchange.getProperty()...
    exchange.setProperty()..
     exchange.getOut().setMessage( exchange.getIn().getBody()); // needed if you want to forward the body also                   
  })
 .multicast()
.to("direct:internal", "direct:external")
                    .end().bean("c");
```